# How to connect to Azure SQL DB using entity framework database first approach using already registered app in Azure

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, azure-sql-database, ef-database-first

I am trying to connect an Azure SQL DB resource using the app id of an already registered application in Azure.
I am using entity framework database first approach.

Comment: What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: U need to follow the same steps as normal sql server. You will give credentials of Azure while giving connectionstring. Thats it.

Comment: Hi Vijay Kulkarni, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an c# Azure web APP, please reference this document: [Quickstart: Use .NET Core (C#) to query an Azure SQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-dotnet-core).

In this quickstart, you'll use .NET Core and C# code to connect to an Azure SQL database. You'll then run a Transact-SQL statement to query data.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few steps to connecting to the Azure SQL database. I suggest reading this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins)

You will need to:

- Add your IP to the Azure SQL firewall
- Create a login via [SQL management studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017)

Once you've completed the above you'll be able to update the [connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-azure/) in your application's web.config to establish a connection.